# Битрикс. Многосайтовость. Настройка главного модуля

Tags: битрикс

Вопрос возможно тривиальный. Есть несколько сайтов на битриксе, на одном не работает регистрация, выдает ошибку

> Ошибка регистрации
> Проверьте, возможно пользователь с такими данными уже существует

В главном модуле отключена регистрация по телефону, но в главном модуле указаны Название сайта и
URL одни, а мне отключить эту функцию надо для другого сайта. Собственно вопрос: Можно ли настройки главного модуля переключать по сайтам?

В доках не смог ни чего найти по этому вопросу( Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

речь о многосайтовости? Нельзя.
База пользователей единая для всех сайтов.
Настройки главного модуля не разделяются по сайтам
[Вот об этом написано](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=103&LESSON_ID=293&LESSON_PATH=8799.3988.293)